# Vertex retried too many times error occurred on running Azure data lake analytic job

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am running USQL job in Azure data lake analytics from Visual Studio and getting below script error. Purpose of my job is to read xml file from Azure blob using Azure blob REST api and extract data and then produce csv file in azure data lake store. I don't see any help in error. Can anyone help my to understand this issue?

> DIAGNOSTICCODE:  223412289
>
> SEVERITY:  Error
>
> COMPONENT:  JobManager_User
>
> SOURCE:  User
>
> ERRORID:  VertexRetriedTooMany
>
> MESSAGE:  Vertex retried too many times
>
> DESCRIPTION:  Vertex SV1_Extract[0][0] retried 24 times.
>
> RESOLUTION:  N/A
>
> HELPLINK:  N/A
>
> DETAILS:   Vertex SV1_Extract[0][0].v23
>   {B0AF5C27-21A5-4011-8044-09A4AB0642C4} failed  Error: Incorrect
>   function.

**UPDATE - More information about my use case:**

I am trying to use "custom user defined operators" in my USQL job because I think my use case can easily be solved using this feature.

My input CSV file is placed in data lake store that contains some values and paths for XML files placed on Azure blob.

In USQL job, I am reading XML file paths from CSV(using USQL) and then reading those XML files from Azure blob storage and extracting values (using code behind c#) and merging my input file with XML values and producing new CSV file in Azure data lake store(Again using USQL).

**Update 2**

I also tried to use Windows Azure storage sdk insted of REST API for accessing blob in code behind and got following error on running job:

```
  "errorId": "E_RUNTIME_USER_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION_FROM_USER_CODE",
  "message": "An unhandled exception from user code has been reported",
  "description": "Unhandled exception from user code: \"The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net'\"\nThe details includes more information including any inner exceptions and the stack trace where the exception was raised.",
  "resolution": "Make sure the bug in the user code is fixed.",
  "helpLink": "",
  "details": "==== Caught exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException\n\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream(Stream target, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n\n   at USQLAppForLogs.LogTable.GetValuesFromBlob(String bloburi)\r\n\n   at USQLAppForLogs.LogTable.Process(IRow input, IUpdatableRow output)\r\n\n   at ScopeEngine.SqlIpProcessor<Extract_0_Data0,SV1_Extract_out0>.GetNextRow(SqlIpProcessor<Extract_0_Data0\\,SV1_Extract_out0>* , SV1_Extract_out0* output) in d:\\data\\ccs\\jobs\\f030ffdf-fc4a-4780-aec5-9067dde49e85_v0\\sqlmanaged.h:line 1821\r\n\n   at RunAndHandleClrExceptions(function<void __cdecl(void)>* code)\n\n==== Inner exception System.Net.WebException\n\nThe remote name could not be resolved: 'xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net'\n\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)"
```

Note that same code works fine locally so I don't think there is any issue in code where I am accessing blob.

Answer (score 2):

This error message normally occurs if the vertex fails due to some system or user error. In this case the error message is not very helpful (Incorrect function).

How are you reading the XML file? You mention that you are using the Azure Blob REST API. That is probably the cause.

If you want to read a file from Windows Azure Blob Stores, you can register the store with your ADLA account (eg., through the Azure Portal, in the ADLA account you can add more stores). Then you can use the wasb URI scheme. An example is here:
https://github.com/MicrosoftBigData/usql/blob/master/Examples/AmbulanceDemos/AmbulanceDemos/1-Ambulance-Unstructured%20Data/1.2-CopyDriversFromWASBToADL.usql

You then can use for example the XML extractors in our XML/JSON sample libraries available here: https://github.com/MicrosoftBigData/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats

Feel free to send me feedback on the sample once you used it.

If this does not address your issue, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is new information for me; however, I am trying to use "custom user defined operators" in my USQL job because I think my use case can easily be solved using this feature. Please see my question with more details about my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the updated information.

The reason your code works locally is that the local execution does not currently impose the external call restrictions that the service's YARN layer currently imposes.

The YARN layer does not allow your code to reach out via http or REST calls. The containers are not allowed to access external resources for security reasons.

So my suggestion is to do one of two things (both require that you register the blob store account as an additional data source):

1. Write a script-generating script (using U-SQL, Powershell, Python, or your favorite script generation language) that will use the EXTRACT on the wasb: URI for your blob store data.
2. If the files have the same schema and are organized according to some path pattern, you can also use file set patterns to refer to a set of files where you don't know the exact filename apriori.

Note that U-SQL currently expects to be able to resolve all file names at compile time.

I will file some bugs on the useless error messages though. And if you like to request a feature that gives you more flexibility in reading files, I encourage you to head to http://aka.ms/adlfeedback to file a request with a use case scenario. That way others can give your suggestion their vote and it helps us in prioritizing the feature in our planning.

Comment: So, that was a problem. I already added my blob store in data lake analytic account. I think your first solution will not work because U-SQL does not resolve file names at run time. Could you please explain your second solution?

I also added one suggestion on your feedback page. [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-azure-data-lake/suggestions/11265501-usql-should-be-able-to-resolve-file-names-at-run-t)

Comment: The first solution is suggesting that you read the files and use the file names to create the script. So the script will know the file names at compile time of the second script. You would have to submit either two scripts or write one powershell script (or other program) that creates the script containing the filenames and then submit the generated script.

Comment: I think it is not a better solution, because I have a huge collection of XML files stored on Azure blob. My CSV file that contains file names is more than 1GB of size. Suggested solution will produce huge script(couple of GB) that seems not an appropriate choice. What do you think?

Comment: I tried to use file set pattern using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621294.aspx. It is under development. I am not able to use this pattern using above help. Could you please point me to some useful example or help?

Comment: 1GB? How many files do you want to read from? Note that currently the fileset feature has a limit of between 500 to 3000 files. So if you want to operate on all files in that 1GB file, that may be a bit much. Please let me know how many files there are though, because we are looking at improving the fileset scale to more files.

Comment: Also, here are some sample scripts that use filesets:

- https://github.com/MicrosoftBigData/usql/tree/master/Examples/AmbulanceDemos/AmbulanceDemos/5-Ambulance-StreamSets-PartitionedTables
- https://github.com/MicrosoftBigData/usql/blob/master/Examples/TweetAnalysis/TweetAnalysis/5-ExtractMentions-RefAsm-FileSet.usql
-

Comment: Around 10 million files.

Comment: Gulp. I would suggest to see if you can merge these files or partition the processing steps into smaller number of files.